# RecordRTC - MediaRecorder API seems unable to record mimeType: video/webm

Tags: reactjs, recorder, recordrtc

I'm using [RecordRTC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recordrtc) for audio and video recording. The issue is when I trying to record audio first then video. I'm getting this error. `MediaRecorder API seems unable to record mimeType: video/webm`.
The Error didn't happen when doing the recording video first and after the audio recording.

Here is the Audio Recorder code

```
const startRecord = () => {
    captureCamera(mic => {
        const recordVideo = RecordRTC(mic, {
            type: 'audio',
            recorderType: StereoAudioRecorder,
            mimeType: 'audio/wav'
        });
        recordVideo.mic = mic;
        setTimeout(() => {
            recordVideo.startRecording();
            setRecorder(recordVideo);
        }, 500);
    });
};

const captureCamera = callback => {
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
            .then(mic => {
                callback(mic);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
};
```

here is the console report of the audio.
[image: Audio Recorder Warninng]

Here is the Video Recorder code

```
const startRecord = () => {
    captureCamera(camera => {
        video.current.muted = true;
        video.current.volume = 0;
        video.current.srcObject = camera;
        const recordVideo = RecordRTC(camera, {
            type: 'video',
            mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9',
            recorderType: MediaStreamRecorder
        });
        recordVideo.camera = camera;

        setTimeout(() => {
            recordVideo.startRecording();
            setRecord(recordVideo);
        }, 500);
    });
};

const captureCamera = callback => {
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true })
            .then(camera => {
                callback(camera);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
};

const stopRecord = () => {
    record.stopRecording(stopRecordingCallback);
};

const stopRecordingCallback = () => {
    getSeekableBlob(record.getBlob(), seekableBlob => {
        const blob = new Blob([seekableBlob], { type: 'video/x-matroska;codecs=avc1,opus' });
        const src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        console.log('File URL', src);
    });
    record.camera.stop();
    record.destroy();
    setRecord(null);
};
```

here is the console report of the video.
[image: Video Recorder Warning]

Answer (score 1):

Not all browsers support recording to `video/webm` using the MediaRecorder API.

On the latest versions, Chrome, Firefox, and Safari all support recording `video/webm;codecs=vp8`, but your mileage may vary since that's the *latest* versions, not the most widely used versions. (e.g. it doesn't work for me on WebKit mobile on iOS)

Here's a helpful support matrix:

https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/simple-demos/isTypeSupported.html

Edit:

You can use `MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm;codec=vp8')` or whatever the MIME-type is to determine if the current browser supports the given codec.